# plt unexpected uneven bar width

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting some very small bar graphs, evenly spaced bins. Code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(4, 4, 1)
ax.bar(np.arange(40),np.arange(40),width=0.8)
```

This produces weird-looking columns - I expect them all to be the same width.
[image: Weirdly spaced columns]

Answer (score -1):

The problem is there is not a high enough pixel density. To fix:

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi=500)#some high density
```

(Not sure if this should be considered a plt bug, as it looks as though there are enough pixels to get a truer rendering).